# Do different warrior weapons offer stat differences?

Tags: cube-world

In cube world. the classes have different weapon types which offer differenty combos and special attacks. An example would be the mage having a staff, wand, or bracelets.

Warriors have 3 types as well: 1 h+shield, dual 1 handed, and 2 handed weapons. The main difference is that there are axes, maces, and swords. The have the same combos (dual mace will hurricane spin just like dual sword).

No other class has this difference, except for ***maybe*** ranger's boomerangs (disc, L, and X types).

So my question is there a difference between weapons of the same type... like sword having more attack speed while axes has higher critical? I'm still a low level where stats are negligible to tell any difference in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each weapon has its own unique stats, but there are general differences that you will spot between families of warrior weapons.

For example, comparing weapons with the same rarity, you'll find that in terms of tempo: swords are faster than axes, which are faster than maces. In terms of damage, the opposite is true: maces generally deal more damage than axes, which deal more damage than swords.

See: http://wiki.cubeworldforum.org/index.php?title=Axe